# "App keep stopping" in the emulator after adding setOnClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-emulator

Whenever I add `setOnClickListener` my app doesn't work in the emulator.

```
package com.example.user.ag

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.connecting_methodes.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.login.*

class ConnectingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connecting)
        showFragmentMethodes()

        ag_login.setOnClickListener{showFragmentLogin()}//when commenting this the app work 
        //textView_st2.setOnClickListener{showFragmentRegister()}
    }

    fun showFragmentMethodes(){
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, ConnectingMethodes())
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }
    fun showFragmentLogin(){
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, Login())
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }
    fun showFragmentRegister(){
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, Register())
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }

}
```

Comment: Add your error log

Comment: try textView_st2.setOnClickListener() { v -> showFragmentRegister() }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The views you're using don't come from `R.layout.activity_connecting` which you're using as your main layout:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.connecting_methodes.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.login.*
```

I'd assume you only set it up with the call to `showFragmentMethodes()`. But this method adds the view asynchronously. Thus `ag_login` is null and your app crashes.

You might want to wait until `ConnectingMethodes` is displayed and then connect the buttons or handle this connection with the fragment itself.

Comment: How can I handle this connection with the fragment itself? in the simplest way

Comment: I think this might be the best approach https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating